# Any Gridview event that fires when I click on a header of a specific column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, objectdatasource

I'm using `asp:ObjectDataSource` with a gridview , and I'm trying to get 
the sortExpression of a gridview , before executing the `SelectMethod` of the `ObjectDataSource` .

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS_Codes"
        runat="server"
        SelectMethod="GetCodes" DataObjectTypeName="DataTable" OnSelected="ODS_Codes_Selected"
        TypeName="Clients_DAL">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="sortExpression" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Is there any gridview event that fires when clicking a header so I would be able to get the name of the clicked column by :

```
ODS_Codes.SelectParameters["sortExpression"].DefaultValue
```

?

Comment: show your grid mark up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `SortExpression="ColName"` on `BoundField`.
2. Use `OnSorting="gridViewSorting"` on gridView_Sorting.

Define event as

```
*protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   DataTable dataTable = gridView.DataSource as DataTable;

   if (dataTable != null)
   {
      DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
      dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);



gridView.DataSource = dataView;
  gridView.DataBind();

   }
}*
```